# How can I evaluate this $\oint_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{R^2 + r^2 -2Rr\cos\theta}}$

Tags: integration

The equation is actually:

$$A(\vec r)=\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi}\int \frac{d\vec l_0}{l}$$
Where $d\vec l_0$ is an infinitesimal element of a circle, $\vec r$ is a position vector from origin(also the centre of the circle) and $l$ is the distance between $d\vec l_0$ and $\vec r$.

I removed the vector signs and changed $dl_0 \rightarrow Rd\theta$ to get:

$$\oint_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{Rd\theta}{\sqrt{R^2 + r^2 -2Rr\cos\theta}}$$

I can't get past this because I don't see anything I can substitute.

Comment: This looks like something from electrodynamics, isn't it?

Comment: Yes ! A is the magnetic vector potential.

Comment: I remember using the substitution $u = \cos \theta$ on something like that but it has $\cos \theta \sin \theta$ on the numerator.

Comment: I would've tried substituting $u=\cos\theta$ but that would get me no where in this problem. The one you're talking about was a surface integration.

Comment: This is typically approached with a multipole expansion, assuming $r \ll R$.

Comment: Because $\cos\theta = 1 - 2\sin^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}$, that integral appears to be [elliptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Notational_variants).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know elliptic integrals yet.

Comment: I don't see how you could avoid elliptic integrals of the first kind.

Comment: I think this is where they introduce Legendre polynomials to describe the various multipoles.  Yes?

Comment: Yes. The denominator can be turned into infinite series sum of Legendre polynomials but how would I proceed on with integrating each term? One extra condition which was given in the question is that the $R<<r$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici In my course they haven't started teaching elliptic integrals yet do I don't know how to apply that here.

Comment: @Weezy. I understood that and I still don't see any way for a rigorous solution.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like a potential of homogenously charged circular loop, the actual formula for its potential is expressible in closed form using the function so called "elliptic integral of the first kind" (as there has been menthioned in the comments), and whoever you are you should definitely know how to use them - the sooner, the better ! Particularlly, complete elliptic integral of the first kind is defined as :

$$\mathrm{K}[k]:=\int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}\varphi}{\sqrt{1-k^2\cos^2\varphi}}\quad\quad\quad,\,|k|<1 $$

One could compute values of this integral numerically, maybe even by hand, because there exist a formula using arithmetic-geometric mean ... It states that

$$\mathrm{K}[k]=\frac{\pi}{2\,\mathrm{agm}(1,\sqrt{1-k^2})}$$

Where procedure agm could be understood as the one fo which these relations apply :

$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{agm}(x,x)&=x\\
\mathrm{agm}(a,b)&=\mathrm{agm}\left(\sqrt{ab}\,,\frac{a+b}{2}\right)
    \end{align}$$

The second relation has to be undertood as a recursive one, it turns out when repeatedly using that raltion both of the arguments converge to the same value, hence for finite number of iteration one could stop going further and say - the are equal, then the identity relation (the first formula) is used...

Proceeding derivation goes like this : at first you see that cos is symmetric around $x=\pi$ line, hence your original integral ($I$) :

$$I=2\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{Rd\theta}{\sqrt{R^2 + r^2 -2Rr\cos\theta}}$$

As it was pointed before, you could use an argument by Andrew D. Hwang, using that you can rewrite the original integral into canonic form presented earlier, with substitution $\theta=2\varphi$ and some algebraic and trigonometric manipulations together with subtitution $\varphi\rightarrow\pi/2-\varphi$ yields:

$$I=\frac{4R}{R+r}\int_{0}^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1 -\frac{4Rr}{(R+r)^2} \sin^2\varphi}}=\frac{4R}{R+r}\mathrm{K}\left[\frac{2\sqrt{Rr}}{R+r}\right]$$

Since absolute value of this argument in the $\mathrm{K}$ function is always less then 1 (AG inequality) - apart from singular point when $r=R$ this formula is valid for **every** nonnegative r.

Note : We can do better than that, argument in elliptic function is rather cumbersome, because of that I definitelly recommend to remeber this reduction formula (Landen's transformation, valid for $|k|<1$) :

$$\mathrm{K}\left[\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{1+k}\right]=(1+k)\,\mathrm{K}[k]$$

Separating the cases into $r<R$ ($r>R$) and defining $k=r/R$ ($k=R/r$) one gets :

$$I=\begin{cases}
4 \mathrm{K}\left[\dfrac{r}{R}\right] & r<R\\
\\
4\dfrac{R}{r}\mathrm{K}\left[\dfrac{R}{r}\right] & r>R\\
\end{cases}$$

Here is a plotted graf of I(r) with R=1 :

[image: Potential of circular hoop]